# Feed dialog - how to change privacy to private - Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

is there a way where i can change the privacy setting when using the Feed Dialog throw my Android application ?

i want to post a private message to current user's wall...

i know that by default the post will be public, but it is important to me that it will be private..

is there a way of doing it with the Feed dialog, or do i must do it from graph api, and then request the needed permissions in order to post on behalf of the user (which i really don't want to... because i managed to create a full and rich application with minimum permissions required )

Comment: The _user_ can select the privacy level when using the Feed dialog, but there is no way of “pre-setting” it when calling the dialog.